# Give the details about the relationship between babel and node.js in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to reactjs,i need to know why we need node.js in react.

Comment: you don't need node.js in react. You need babel to transpile your ES6 / JSX code to ES5 in order to be understandable by a large panel of browsers

Comment: I like to know why we need node.js for babel compiler

Comment: Please stop spamming SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need node.js in react. However, you can use it to help you manage your dependencies, or automate some tasks.

Examples:

https://babeljs.io/repl/ to compile JSX code to JS (however it's optional)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep to take care of your bower dependencies and put it in code automatically (not connected with React directly)

Comment: happy for ur immediate replay... give some example with explanation

Comment: I've updated my answet with some examples for you

Answer (score 1):

As well as using it to automate build and bundling tools as Karol mentioned, you can optionally use node for server side aka universal aka isomorphic rendering.

Comment: Yes, of course! I should've mentioned it

Comment: happy for ur answer